# boost asio behaviour - calling ios_service::run from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use boost::asio deadline timer for delayed function call as follows

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class MyTest {
public:
    MyTest()
    :_invokeCount(0),
     _handleCount(0)
    {}

    void handler(int i)
    {
        std::cout<<"\t\tHandled " <<i << std::endl;
        ++_handleCount;
    }
    void RunIOService()
    {
        std::cout<<"\tStarted :"<< _invokeCount<< std::endl;
        _ios.run();
        std::cout<<"\tFinished "<< _invokeCount << std::endl;
    }
    void invokeTimer()
    {
        std::cout<<"invoked " << ++_invokeCount << std::endl;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(_ios, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5));
        t.async_wait(boost::bind(&MyTest::handler, this, _invokeCount));
        boost::thread th = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyTest::RunIOService, this));
    }
    void PrintCount()
    {
        std::cout<<"Count = "<< _invokeCount << std::endl;
    }
    void Wait()
    {
        while (_invokeCount > _handleCount) {
            std::cout<<"X ";
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

private:
    int _invokeCount;
    int _handleCount;
    boost::asio::io_service _ios;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyTest test;
    for (int k=0; k<5; ++k) {
        test.invokeTimer();
        Sleep(40);
    }
    test.Wait();
    test.PrintCount();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of this application is not as I expected:-

```
invoked 1
    Started :1
        Handled 1
    Finished 1
invoked 2
    Started :2
    Finished 2
invoked 3
    Started :3
        Handled 2
    Finished 3
invoked 4
    Started :4
        Handled 3
    Finished 4
invoked 5
    Started :5
        Handled 4
    Finished 5
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I expected every handler to be called before ios_service::run returns and it doesn't seem so from the output ( missing output between Started:2 and Finished:2). Also, the application never exits. i.e the 5th handler never gets invoked.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added ios_service::reset() after each ios_service::run() and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. You probably don't need 5 threads.  Why don't you create a single thread and fire the events into that single ioservice instance running in the thread
2. Try using `io_service::work` in the thread run function to keep the `io_service` in scope while all your requests are handled.
3. When your wait finishes, stop your `io_service`, join your thread and let your program exit
4. Read here about `io_service::work`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html

Comment: Thanks - in the actual application, the function equivalent to invokeTimer is event based so my thinking was to launch a short-lived thread when an event arrives rather than run a separate thread for the life time of the application (not sure about the load of ios_service::work).

Comment: Sammy - you can trust `work` to be efficient: it was precisely designed for this purpose. Sleeping threads in a thread pool don't have runtime overhead. `io_service` is actually a threadsafe task queue and background threads just sleep while waiting for work to arrive. _(I'd say using Boost Asio with a 'thread per event' model is putting the cart before the horse)_

Comment: (PS. The overhead of reusing the same queue/threads (i.e. when using `io_service::work`) is definitely less than starting an new thread. Eeek)

Answer (score 0):

boost::asio::ioservice::reset() should be called before later set of invocations of the run().
as the boost doc say:
 This function must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_service being stopped or running out of work. This function allows the io_service to reset any internal state, such as a "stopped" flag.

This function must not be called while there are any unfinished calls to the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions.